# Get results column having numbers with in brackets

Tags: mysql, parentheses

How to get results column having numbers with in brackets?

Actual table:

```
--------------
|id|name     |
--------------
|1 |abc      |
-------------
|2 |rav (21) |
--------------
|3 |nag (123)|
--------------
```

Required results:

```
--------------
|id|name     |
--------------
|2 |rav (21) |
--------------
|3 |nag (123)|
--------------
```

Comment: I've gleaned that this is a SQL question.  Now just post a query and tell us which database you are using.

Comment: @mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP` to match parentheses terms:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE name REGEXP '\\([0-9]+\\)';
```

### Demo

Comment: how to remove that column having numbers with in brackets. ex: abc(23) -> abc

Comment: If you want to _delete_ such matching records, then use: `DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE name REGEXP '\\([0-9]+\\)'`

Comment: not delete records. only replace ex: abc(23) -> abc

Comment: @SureshBabuEede You can't do that with base MySQL; there is no regex replace support.  You may look into using a UDF for that.